# Why would different versions of openssl produce different hashed filenames for the same root cert?

Tags: windows, ssl, solaris, openssl

OpenSSL - Solaris - Windows

When I run c_rehash (OpenSSL 0.9.x in Solaris) and c_rehash (OpenSSL 1.1.x in Windows), the same exact cert.pem file gets converted to a .0 file with a completely different filename.

(Windows) cert.pem => 4e12356.0

(Solaris) cert.pem => 3e121e8.0

Why is this? Shouldn't the hash be the exact same regardless of which version of OpenSSL I'm using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hash used for these names changed when moving to OpenSSL 1.0. You can revert to the old behaviour using `-subject_hash_old`. See the [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html#DISPLAY_OPTIONS):

> **-hash**
>
> synonym for ``-subject_hash'' for backward compatibility reasons.
>
> **-subject_hash_old**
>
> outputs the ``hash'' of the certificate subject name using the older algorithm as used by OpenSSL versions before 1.0.0.

There's more background information in [this message](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg26962.html). Essentially, the hash algorithm changed from MD5 to SHA-1.