# DER encoded hash

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, stunnel, x509

according to the manpage of stunnel4

> the certificates in this directory should be named XXXXXXXX.0 where XXXXXXXX is the **hash value of the DER encoded subject of the cert** (the first 4 bytes of the MD5 hash in least significant byte order).

How can I produce a such thing ?

I tried, unsuccessfully :s :

```
openssl x509 -in cert.crt -inform PEM -out cert.der -outform DER
```

then

```
openssl dgst cert.der
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
# openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -hash
c59f9aac
```

This will give you the hash that OpenSSL is expecting to get for a certificates directory.

Comment: The documentation for stunnel4 is probably not up to date, but with a modern version of OpenSSL, you'd need `-subject_hash_old` to produce an MD5 hash, since `-hash` would use SHA-1. (Details [here](http://serverfault.com/a/401120/47187).) I guess stunnel4 might not care either way and delegate all this to the version of OpenSSL it's linked to.

Comment: Yes, any application using OpenSSL does (or at least should) delegate all this to the underlying OpenSSL library.

Answer (score 2):

### `c_rehash`, `openssl rehash`

#### Create symbolic links to files named by the hash values.

See [`man c_rehash`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/c_rehash.html) or `openssl rehash`:

> On some platforms, the `openssl rehash` command is available as an external script called `c_rehash`. They are functionally equivalent, except for minor differences noted [*in the manpages*].